# COM custom interface, member function pointer arguments get corrupted

Tags: winapi, com

I've been using COM few years, but never having to write an interface, so that gets me little confused.

I have an interface, let it be called `IFoo`, defined as

```
import "unknwn.idl";
[
    object,
    uuid( // guidgen generated one // ),
] interface IFoo : IClassFactory
{
    HRESULT Bar(const BYTE * pb, ULONG cb );
};
```

which I have compiled using MIDL-generated files and registered into the Windows registry. I also have made a local COM server, essentially which implements IFoo. In this I followed "Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\com\fundamentals\dcom\simple\" sample code replacing IStream by my own IFoo.

I can create an instance of IFoo in my client code and all that, but the member function 'Bar' just doesn't work. I cannot figure out why, see, when I call

```
IFoo->Bar( 0x42A110, 352 ); // address just an example
```

the arguments are seen by the server side as

```
Bar( 0x560E20, 352 );
```

Address-values are not important, but what is this translation here?? Help appreciated :) Currently, I just pass a pointer to beginning of a `std::vector`'s data which might just be inaccessible across process boundaries, but that doesn't explain the translation.

Comment: Inheriting your interface from `IClassFactory` is already a symptom that you are doing it wrong. You are unlikely to ever need to extend class factory. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Roman for pointing out, I might very well be... In sample I refer to, there is actual class implementation `CSimpleObject`and a separate factory class `CClassFactory`, so I thought why not adding them into a single entity.

Comment: Typical COM instantiation involves discovering a factory and asking it to create an instance. API makes it quite so often transparent, so that no questions are even asked. On server side (where you implement COM object), you don't need to bother too. Any framework will provide you default and perfectly suitable class factory. Even if you do everything from ground, there is no real reason. need or advantage to merge class factory with real object. You will stumble very soon on something where it is rather an obstacle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments passed across COM boundaries are usually marshalled. This is done because the COM boundary may be a machine boundary (in the case of DCOM) or a process boundary (in the case of out of process COM components). The COM infrastructure does this marshalling on your behalf and what's done will depend on the data types involved. Read up on Appartments, Marshalling and Proxies and Stubs (or take a look at [COM IDL & Interface Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861002254)) if you're interested in the details.

Given that marshalling will be required for your arguments you next need to understand how IDL declares the arguments to your function. The IDL you've written doesn't pass enough information to the MIDL compiler for the proxy and stub to be generated correctly. That `BYTE *pb` could be a single byte or an array and the value could be passed in to the function or returned from it... Now, I know that it's an array because I can see you have a length specified after it, but MIDL doesn't know that. Likewise I'm guessing it's data being passed into the function as `cb` isn't a pointer and so you can't be telling the caller how much data you've returned but only how large the array being passed in is... To inform MIDL that it needs to marshal a number of bytes rather than just one you need to tell it that `pb` is an array. You do this like this:

```
HRESULT Bar(
   [in, size_is(cb)] BYTE *pb,
   [in] ULONG cb);
```

What we're doing here is telling MIDL that the data in both `pb` and `cb` needs to be marshalled IN to the function and that `pb` represents an array of BYTE which is `cb` bytes long.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I'll check what an impact it'll have on my case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although the address translation didn't go away, now it appears that with your modifications the system actually copies my buffer 1-to-1 for its whole length, so the data - albeit in different address - transfers correctly :) I definitely need to read more about COM and MIDL.

Comment: The address translation can only go away if no marshalling is required; so in proc components, etc..